# transfer file from VM instance to cloud storage, get error message of 403 insufficient permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I could copy files from gs bucket to VM instance using gsutil cp. But when I try do reverse, cp files from VM instance to gs bucket, I got the  error message of 403 insufficient permission. Anyone know what cause this and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the bucket [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#ch-roles), as well as the objects within. You need to make sure that whatever account you are using, has full rights to that bucket or object.

Alternatively, you can create a new bucket with full control permissions and copy the files there..and then you can see if the error is replicated or not . I replicated on a test account with owner permissions on the bucket and did not come across the error you have specified.